# How to sort numbers listed in a list

Tags: list, sorting

I have a list : [[4, 7, 50], [9, 10, 20]]

I want to write these numbers to a text file
I want the output to look like this: 4, 7, 9, 10, 20, 50

how do I sort each number in the sub-list?

Comment: Will this list always contain 2 sublist?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a flat() over the array and then a sort() to show the result as you want to.

See documentation for flat and sort for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort

Comment: Thank You, I'll try that

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it.

1. If you only have 2 sublists in a list, you can use merge sort.
2. If the size of the data is not too much, merge all the sublists into 1 list and sort that final list.

How to do it?

1. Create a result list, empty.
2. Iterate over your list, and add each item to the result list.
3. sort the result list.
4. write it to file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helps